# cfmail not working on cf9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

CFMail was working fine on coldfusion 9. Then suddenly it stopped sending the email. The log says email sent sucessfully but no one received it.

It seems it is a know issue as discussed here - [adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/585718)

Anyone has got any idea then please tell me. client is going mad here.

Comment: What version of CF9 are you on?

Comment: Is there anything in your undelivr directory?

Comment: yeah it says it is delivered. No error nothing.

Comment: Have you already checked if your server could send **any** email? (e.g. from console) or if your settings for relaying server are still existing (CFIDE/administrator -> Server Settings -> Mail)?

Comment: Is this your [blogpost](http://ethermuse.blogspot.com/2011/10/adobe-coldfusion-cf-mailer-dies.html) describing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. My client changed the from email from the setting page which we provide and they entered an  invalid email address which was then failing at the SMTP server end with "invalid return path" as error.

After adding a valid email id it worked.